# Hive SQL query to replicate vlookup

Tags: sql, hive, vlookup

I have 3 tables:

Table A:

```
Campaign               Order No          Cust ID
Campaign-Campaign A    Order No-89000    Cust ID-12376;
Campaign-Campaign B    Order No-89003    Cust ID-62376
```

Table B

```
First Order Date               Cust ID
First Order Date-02-05-2018    Cust_ID-12376;
First Order Date-09-02-2017    Cust_ID-76546
```

Table C:

```
Campaign                Campaign Launch            Campaign End Date
Campaigns-Campaign A    Launch Date-02-02-2018     End Date-02-28-2018;
Campaigns-Campaign B    Launch Date-09-01-2017     End Date-12-05-2017
```

Both of them have 5 campaigns and all 5 campaigns have different flight dates. I trying to find new orders generated b/w campaign dates to attribute it to specific campaigns so if the first order date of a customer falls b/w specific campaign dates, then that's a new customer from that campaign.

My code is:

```
select
    a.campaign,
    b.first_order_date,
    a.order_no
from
    table_a as a                            
    left join table_b as b on a.cust_id=b.cust_id                           
where
    a.campaign IN
    (
        select
            distinct(campaign)
        from
            table_c
    )
    and
    b.first_order_date between '2017-08-17' AND '2017-09-30'
group by
    a.campaign,
    b.first_order_date,
    a.order_no;
```

I want the query to select first order date from `Table C` with reference to Campaign Name. Pick first order date b/w campaign launch date & campaign end date next to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample data please

Comment: Just edited. Let me know. I think it may be another sub query to pick launch and end date from Table C but I haven't figured it out yet, the lookup part.

Comment: can you show us what the output you want would look like? Not sure I understand.

Comment: The output should be>> (Campaign) Campaign A -- (First Order Date) 02-05-2018 -- (Order No) 89000   Meaning order no 89000 was placed by a customer between Campaign A's flight dates and is the first time that customer placed that order with us. So we can say that, that new customer who has never bought before was brought in by Campaign A.